# Kohana не корректно работает на Денвере

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, kohana

Всем привет. Сейчас делаю локально мультиязычный сайт на фреймворке Kohana. Появилась небольшая трабла. Локальный адрес сайта - http://autoclub. Когда набираю http://autoclub/ru/ - пишет **The requested URL ru was not found on this server.**

base_url у меня вычисляется следующим образом: вытягиваю из урла алиас языка, то есть **ru** и в зависимости от языка устанавливаю base_url

```
switch (I18n::$lang) {
    case 'fi':
        $base_url = '/';
        break;
    case 'ru':
        $base_url = '/ru/';
        break;
    case 'es':
        $base_url = '/es/';
        break;
    default:
        $base_url = '/';
        I18n::lang('fi');
}
```

На хостинге такая конструкция работает как часы, а локально на Денвере пишет **The requested URL ru was not found on this server.**

Уже что только не пробовал - и ставил base_url напрямую без этого switch-case, Rewrite base менял (ставил там /www и прочую хрень), убирал и добавлял слеши везде, а оно не поддается.

Файл htaccess на данный момент стандартный:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Вот содержимое файла vhosts.conf по хосту http://autoclub

```
# Host /home/autoclub/www (3): 
#Listen 127.0.0.1:80
#NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  DocumentRoot "X:/home/autoclub/www"  
  ServerName "autoclub"
  ServerAlias "autoclub" "www.autoclub" 
  ScriptAlias /cgi/ "/home/autoclub/cgi/"
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/autoclub/cgi-bin/"
</VirtualHost>

# Host /home/autoclub/www (4): 
#Listen 127.0.0.1:443
#NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
  SSLEngine on
  DocumentRoot "X:/home/autoclub/www"  
  ServerName "autoclub"
  ServerAlias "autoclub" "www.autoclub" 
  ScriptAlias /cgi/ "/home/autoclub/cgi/"
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/autoclub/cgi-bin/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Думаю, что это связано с настройкой апача, но куда именно копать?

Comment: AllowOverride all в конфиге апача для данной директории есть ?

Comment: @eicto, завтра (точнее уже сегодня) зайду на робочем компе и посмотрю. Может когда-то что-то и менял там в конфигах

Comment: @eicto, обновил вопрос. В файле httpd.conf ничего интересного не было, а вот в файле vhosts.conf прописаны настройки для виртуальных хостов

Comment: Уважаемый @Iranda, я назвал топик исходя из проблемы, чтобы пользователи сразу смогли сориентироваться о чем идет речь. Я уже достаточно долго на форуме и знаю, как правильно называть топики. Сразу теряется смысл темы и непонятно о чем идет речь. Попрошу в дальнейшем не переименовывать необдуманно тему.